# Unstable connection between peers on a private network

Tags: go-ethereum, network, connections

I created a private net, I've been trying to connect two Ethereum nodes because I need one of them to mine the transaction made by the other.  The two nodes are on different machines and networks. I made sure they have the same genesis file and network id. Below there are the commands from the two machines:

Node 1

```
geth --rpcport 1338 --rpcaddr "192.168.1.146" --rpccorsdomain "*" --genesis Documents/MyEthereum/MyCustomGenesis.json --datadir Documents/MyEthereum/MyEthereumData --rpc --networkid 1555 --ipcdisable --port 30301 --maxpeers 1 console
```

Node 2

```
geth --rpcport 1338 --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --genesis Documents/MyEthereum/MyCustomGenesis.json --datadir Documents/MyEthereum/MyEthereumData --rpc --networkid 1555 --bootnodes "enode://a0bc79da8c0d38f59e3d9eaa4de05da568d6334c5b9ba29c531d8a9cf3d740cd606d924707231b0697e803b5e40c25f0e58482bbdb524d0825d5b47a166de47e@192.168.1.146:30301" --ipcdisable --maxpeers 1 --port 30301 console
```

Even though the two nodes find each other, the connection between them goes down and the following message appears:

```
Header #748 [39535e19] broke chain ancestry
```

Setting the verbosity to 10 I can see the following log:

```
I0824 11:46:00.301044     986 downloader.go:228] Registering peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5
I0824 11:46:02.583638     986 server.go:586] Accepted conn 94.119.64.151:50420
I0824 11:46:04.344266     986 downloader.go:252] Attempting synchronisation: a0bc79da8c0d38f5, head [e0b42918…], TD 248597994
I0824 11:46:04.344424     986 downloader.go:337] Synchronising with the network using: a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [eth/63]
I0824 11:46:04.344438     986 downloader.go:905] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: retrieving remote chain height
I0824 11:46:04.344556     986 peer.go:251] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [eth/63] fetching 1 headers from e0b42918, skipping 0 (reverse = false)
I0824 11:46:04.423350     986 fetcher.go:258] [eth/62] filtering 1 headers
I0824 11:46:04.423513     986 downloader.go:953] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: looking for common ancestor
I0824 11:46:04.423639     986 peer.go:258] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [eth/63] fetching 192 headers from #1153, skipping 0 (reverse = false)
I0824 11:46:04.594060     986 downloader.go:1015] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: common ancestor: #1344 [2770f88f…]
I0824 11:46:04.594136     986 downloader.go:1317] Downloading node state data
I0824 11:46:04.594176     986 downloader.go:1269] Downloading block bodies from #1345
I0824 11:46:04.594190     986 downloader.go:1293] Downloading receipts from #1345
I0824 11:46:04.594154     986 downloader.go:1084] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: downloading headers from #1345
I0824 11:46:04.594252     986 downloader.go:1118] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: fetching 192 headers from #1345
I0824 11:46:04.594290     986 peer.go:258] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [eth/63] fetching 192 headers from #1345, skipping 0 (reverse = false)
I0824 11:46:04.892489     986 downloader.go:1186] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: schedule 192 headers from #1345
I0824 11:46:04.892618     986 queue.go:335] Header #1350 [b6523ae1] broke chain ancestry
I0824 11:46:04.892639     986 downloader.go:1214] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: stale headers
I0824 11:46:04.892657     986 downloader.go:1215] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: header download terminated
I0824 11:46:04.892686     986 downloader.go:1309] Receipt download terminated: receipt download canceled (requested)
I0824 11:46:04.892707     986 downloader.go:1356] Node state data download terminated: state data download canceled (requested)
I0824 11:46:04.892705     986 downloader.go:1285] Block body download terminated: block body download canceled (requested)
I0824 11:46:04.892743     986 downloader.go:339] Synchronisation terminated after 548.302912ms
I0824 11:46:04.892767     986 downloader.go:263] Removing peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5: action from bad peer ignored
I0824 11:46:04.892783     986 handler.go:163] Removing peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5
I0824 11:46:04.892790     986 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5
I0824 11:46:04.892810     986 peer.go:180] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 192.168.1.146:30301: locally requested disconnect: Useless peer
I0824 11:46:04.893002     986 handler.go:244] Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 [eth/63]: message handling failed: EOF
I0824 11:46:04.893044     986 server.go:686] Removed Peer a0bc79da8c0d38f5 192.168.1.146:30301 (Useless peer)
```

I'm aware it may seem a duplicate question but I can't understand the meaning of these messages. Any help appreciated.